# Can I capture div#Id and put in Google Analytic Event

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Can I do like this

```
var eLabel = $('#example_placeholder').html();
```

and put eLabel into this

```
ga('send', {
'hitType': 'event',          // Required.
'eventCategory': 'cash',   // Required. privilege acquisition creditcard installment
'eventAction': 'ClickView',      // Required.
'eventLabel': eLabel
});
```

Comment: wow thanks. Now what if elements not yet created on the page, how can I capture that value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. You can shorten things like this as well:

```
ga('send','event','cash','ClickView',$('#example_placeholder').html());
```

Comment: wow thanks. Now what if elements not yet created on the page, how can I capture that value?